# How can I make javascript formatter to avoid new line after 'const'

Tags: javascript, formatter

Could anybody explain to me how to proceed to prevent the eclipse editor from inserting a new line after the JavaScript reserved word 'const'. The current state of the JavaScript code formatter makes a constant declaration to be as follows:

```
const
const-name=...;
```

Whereas the intended appearance of such a constant declaration would be:

```
const const-name=...;
```

I cannot find the right setting option within the JavaScript Formatter that gets the intended appearance.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I noticed the same issue. Unfortunately it's a [known bug](https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=399501) that was not scheduled since 2013.

Comment: This does not really answer the question. If you have a different question, you can ask it by clicking [Ask Question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask). You can also [add a bounty](http://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/set-bounties) to draw more attention to this question once you have enough [reputation](http://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation). - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/11929199)

Comment: If it's a known bug that was not scheduled, it was not fixed till today and therefore there is no solution. That's the answer! ;-)